# jquery not changing css background-image property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background-image

I am trying to make a simple slideshow that changes the css background-image using [JQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Fiddle: http://jsbin.com/xinihokuso/edit?js,console

```js
var images = [
  "http://static1.squarespace.com/static/550b669de4b0d91b0f49935d/t/551b6575e4b0c2174c3a6f54/1427858806833/flowers.jpg?format=1500w",
  "http://cimages.prvd.com/is/image/ProvideCommerce/PF_15_R105_MINIMAL_VA0211_W1_SQ?$PFCProductImage$",
  "http://media02.hongkiat.com/ww-flower-wallpapers/purplecrocus.jpg",
  "http://www.ninthstreetflowers.com/smp/Smp1/images/flower4.jpg",
  "http://magic-spells-and-potions.com/images/flower-language-vertical.png",
];

var i = 0;

var div = $('.header_summer');

$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("loaded");

  setTimeout(changeBack, 1000);
});

function changeBack() {
  i = i = ++i % images.length;

  if (i > images.length) {
    i = 0;
  }

  console.log('url(' + images[i] + ') no-repeat 0 0;');

  div.css('background', 'url(' + images[i] + ') no-repeat 0 0;');

  setTimeout(changeBack, 5000);
}
```

```css
<div class="header_summer"></div>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">

.header_summer  {
  background: url('http://static1.squarespace.com/static/550b669de4b0d91b0f49935d/t/551b6575e4b0c2174c3a6f54/1427858806833/flowers.jpg?format=1500w') no-repeat 0 0; 
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 920px; /* 800px; */
}

</style>
```

Everything looks right, the console is showing the correct CSS background-image value on each cycle, but all that is happening is the original image from the initial declared CSS is showing. Any ideas?

Please don't tell me to try to create unique CSS selectors for each image and simply change the style. That is not what I am trying to achieve here.

Comment: See my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the semi-colon(;) after declaring the pixels.

```
 div.css('background', 'url(' + images[i]  + ') no-repeat 0px 0px');
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/ez8cgsx7/8/

Comment: that's got it! Thanks!

Comment: Sure. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the class selector, it should be:

```
var div = $('.header_summer');
```

Also, `background-image` does not take that many parameters:

```
div.css('background-image', 'url("../tpl/mbmhv1/images/' + images[i] + '")');
```

Use `background` if you want parameters

Edit:

You need to add some css to your element

```
.header_summer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsbin.com/zufekurapo/edit?output

```js
var images = [
  "http://static1.squarespace.com/static/550b669de4b0d91b0f49935d/t/551b6575e4b0c2174c3a6f54/1427858806833/flowers.jpg?format=1500w",
  "http://cimages.prvd.com/is/image/ProvideCommerce/PF_15_R105_MINIMAL_VA0211_W1_SQ?$PFCProductImage$",
  "http://media02.hongkiat.com/ww-flower-wallpapers/purplecrocus.jpg",
  "http://www.ninthstreetflowers.com/smp/Smp1/images/flower4.jpg",
  "http://magic-spells-and-potions.com/images/flower-language-vertical.png",
];

var i = 0;

var div = $('.header_summer');

$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("loaded");

  setTimeout(changeBack, 1000);
});

function changeBack() {
  i = i = ++i % images.length;

  if (i > images.length) {
i = 0;
  }

  console.log(images[i]);

  div.css('background', 'url(\''+images[i] + '\') no-repeat');

  setTimeout(changeBack, 2000);
}
```

```css
.header_summer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header_summer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you must append `div.css({ background-repeat:"no-repeat", background-position: "0px 0px" })` in order to keep the css effect on image.

Answer (score 1):

**Check your selector and scope**

If you want to target the element you provided in your example, your jQuery selector should include a `.` to indicate you are targeting an element with the class of "header_summer" :

```
var div = $(".header_summer");
```

Additionally, declaring this before your `$(document).ready(){ ... });` block is going to cause some issues as jQuery will not be available at the time. Consider declaring your variable and then setting it within that function :

```
var div;
$(document).ready(function(){
     div = $(".header_summer");
});
```

**Simplify setting your background**

Currently, you are attempting to set all kinds of other properties in addition to just `background-image` within your CSS call. If you want to do this, you should consider using `background` instead of `background-image` :

```
div.css("background", "url('" + images[i] + "') no-repeat 0px 0px");
```

or if you are using `background-image` then just set the background :

```
div.css("background", "url('" + images[i] + "')");
```

**Putting it all together**

[image]

```css
.header_summer {
  background: url('http://static1.squarespace.com/static/550b669de4b0d91b0f49935d/t/551b6575e4b0c2174c3a6f54/1427858806833/flowers.jpg?format=1500w') no-repeat 0px 0px;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 920px;
  /* 800px; */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Flowers and stuff...</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Your element to switch through -->
  <div class='header_summer'></div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Define your images
    var images = [
 "http://static1.squarespace.com/static/550b669de4b0d91b0f49935d/t/551b6575e4b0c2174c3a6f54/1427858806833/flowers.jpg?format=1500w",
      "http://cimages.prvd.com/is/image/ProvideCommerce/PF_15_R105_MINIMAL_VA0211_W1_SQ?$PFCProductImage$",
      "https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s--8a-AXhau--/c_scale,fl_progressive,q_80,w_800/zec3un8rzcmblrdlyswb.jpg",
      "http://media02.hongkiat.com/ww-flower-wallpapers/purplecrocus.jpg",
      "http://www.ninthstreetflowers.com/smp/Smp1/images/flower4.jpg",
      "http://magic-spells-and-potions.com/images/flower-language-vertical.png",
    ];
     // Define your variables
    var i = 0;
    var div;
    $(function() {
      // Set up your div
      div = $('.header_summer');
      console.log("loaded");
      setTimeout(changeBack, 1000);
    });

    function changeBack() {
      i = ++i % images.length;
      if (i > images.length) {
        i = 0;
      }
      console.log('url("' + images[i] + '");');
      div.css('background-image', "url('" + images[i] + "')");
      setTimeout(changeBack, 5000);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the concise answer, the issue with my code was in fact the semicolons after the css declaration - so i have marked that as the correct answer, but your code will serve as a good example for people with the same problem.

Comment: No problem. Just glad that everything is working. Issues like these can be a pain to troubleshoot.

Comment: do you have anysuggestions on how I might make the transition nicer, I was going to append .fadeIn(1000) to the line that sets the new css params, but it seems to be loading it in the BG befoe removing the orig. Any ideas? perhaps this is for a new question...

Comment: Add a transition via `transition: 0.5s` on your `.header_summer` CSS class.

Comment: just tried it, no joy. See my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37333917/jquery-css-background-image-slideshow-with-transtion-effect

Answer (score 0):

Change a single line of code:

```
div.css('background-image', 'url(' + images[i] + ')').css('background-repeat','no-repeat').css('background-position','left top');
```